# Does Family Sharing consumes extra storage?

Tags: ios, mac, icloud, photos

I already have my images uploaded to iCloud using Photos.app on my Mac and iOS devices. If I share some of that photos with my Family album, they will be re-uploaded (consuming more storage on my iCloud account) or they will be shared with some kind of "link" to my original photo?

Also, if the photo is re-uploaded, does that results in some kind of compression or quality loss?

Answer (score 1):

All Albums in the Apple Ecosystem are only references to the main photos album (Camera Roll or All Photos).